# KOMA: Margin notes only on outer side of two-column document?

Tags: koma-script, two-column, marginpar

For some part of a two-column `scrbook` of mine, I need to actually get a *three*-column layout: Two columns text, and a third column with a table (or a boxed enumeration, that would work too).

Both columns of text and the table / enumeration have to be shorter than a page (for contextual reasons), so column / page breaks are not an issue here.

I was hoping to somehow commandeer `geometry` and `\marginpar` (or similar) for the purpose - setting a 1/3rd textwidth margin with `\newgeometry`, and then pushing my "third column" there.

However, setting up margins for a `twocolumn` document gives a margin *on both sides of the page*.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\marginpar{Hello.}
\lipsum[1-4]
\marginpar{You.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output...]

Now, I *could* tweak the page geometry a bit so that the inner margin gets pushed off-page, and set the `\marginpar` (or whatever) in the second column on recto pages and in the first column on verso pages...

But before I do that hack-ish thing: Is there, by any chance, a switch in either *KOMA* or *geometry* that would tell LaTeX that I want only *one* margin on the *outer* side of the page, with `\marginpar`'s from the inner column being pushed there too?

**Edit:** Or generally a better way to achieve a "temporary third column"?

**Edit 2:** Apparently, no "easy" way to get margin paragraphs "moved over". On second thought, it wouldn't make much sense, from a typographical point of view, since it wouldn't be clear which column is annotated. Ah well, I'll hack my way around it. ;-)

Voting to close as "too localized" myself.

Comment: Don't use `geometry`: use KOMA script's own `typearea` package...

Comment: I have no experience with it, but the `multicol` package should allow you to have 3 columns for some part (or all) the document.

Comment: @Seamus: Thanks for the hint at `typearea`. But since I am trying to emulate an existing layout, specifying widths explicitly via `geometry` is actually easier for me than handling the "more comfortable" automatic calculations of `typearea`. (Perhaps in my next project. ;-) )

Comment: With `\areaset{Width}{Height}` you can set the type block to a specific width and height...

Answer (score 2):

Add the option \documentclass[`mpinclude=true`]{scrreprt}, which expands the margin space, so `\marginpar{...}` perhaps can be used the way you want.